# How and when do I pay for luggage?

Tags: air-travel, luggage

I recently purchased a flight with STA and it only just dawned on me about luggage. I'm very new to the while flying thing and well I was unsure. My luggage will be over that which is allowed for carry on.

How and when will I pay for my luggage - through STA or at the airport?

Comment: How much luggage is included in your ticket? Some airlines do not include any luggage, most do include one or two piece of carry on and some allow check-in luggage, some even more than one piece, without extra payment. Mostly it is on your ticket and/or on the airlines website.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you pay for excess luggage when you check in, though some companies offer lower fees if you pay at the time of buying your ticket. If that were true for your booking, however, the travel agent should have mentioned it.

It's also common to see lower fees if you pay through online check-in. Because these policies vary from one airline to another, you should check your airline's web pages to determine their policy.